# Excel Time format data getting converted to text value in XML

Tags: xml, excel

Thanks for viewing my question.

This is basicaly excel I am working on

```
**Shift Start Time  Break 1 Time    Lunch Time  Break 2 Time    Shift End Time**
     7:00:00      8:30:00            12:00:00         14:30:00         16:30:00
```

when I am convertiong this excel to XML from my .Net code the time values in Xcl are getting converted to text so the data is getting currupt.

```
Shift_x0020_Start_x0020_Time=''0.291666666666667''  
Break_x0020_1_x0020_Time=''0.354166666666667'' 
Lunch_x0020_Time=''0.5'' 
Break_x0020_2_x0020_Time=''0.604166666666667'' 
Shift_x0020_End_x0020_Time=''0.6875''
```

This is how the XML generated looks. I dont want this to happen and I want to hold the actual time values entred by user. Kindly suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as numbers in Excel, with time of day as a decimal fraction.  Thus 12 Noon is exactly 0.5 (half a day).  You must convert the fractions to hours:minutes:seconds yourself in your .net code before writing the XML.

```
n is the number given to you by Excel

h       = n*24
hours   = floor(h)
m       = (h-hours) * 60
minutes = floor(m)
seconds = floor((m-minutes) * 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who came here to find a solution for .net. This is how you could do it in .net.

You could use:

```
public void FractionTOTime()
{
    TimeSpan time = null;

    time = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble("2.0833333333333332E-2"));

    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString());

}
```